# Cooler Master Hyper TX3 evo push pins

Tags: installation, cpu, motherboard, cooling

I've failed to install the **Cooler Master hyper TX3 evo** fan on **ASRock X79 extreme9** motherboard (CPU is **Intel Core i7 3820** if that would help).

I'm sure that I followed the manual right the problem is that i can't close push pins no matter how hard i press ( within limit, i don't want to split the motherbaord in half).

I don't know what causing this can anyone help please ?

Comment: Your motherboard has an LGA 2011 socket, and your HSF is only compatible with LGA 1366 / 1156 / 1155 / 1151 / 1150 / 775 according to http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/X79%20Extreme9/ and http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/hyper-tx3-evo/ use pcpartpicker.com to find a suitable HSF for your application.

Comment: @spikey_richie is there a way to use screws instead ?

Comment: You could use some threaded bolts and some nuts, but you'd have to rip out the mounts on the HSF mounting plate. Safer to just buy a new HSF. It's also likely that you can't lock the existing HSF down because the mounts are in the wrong place, so using screws/blots won't really help. You might be able to retro-fit a mounting plate from another HSF, but it's not really worth the hassle.

Comment: @spikey_richie can you recommend me a fan ?

Comment: https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/list/ add your motherboard, then go to add CPU cooler and see what's applicable.

Comment: @spikey_richie when i read LGA 2011-v3 or LGA 2011 it means that it's compatible right ?

Comment: @Venay - You will have to research if the layout of the pins on those two sockets are identical.

Comment: @Ramhound how can i do that ?

Comment: How can you do what exactly?  You have to research if the layout is the same, one way of doing that is finding a single CPU fan that supports both sockets, that typically indicates the layout of the mounting brackets have not moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong heat-sink fan (HSF) for your application, your motherboard is an LGA 2011 socket and your HSF is not compatible with that socket. Find a new HSF that's compatible with the LGA 2011 socket. I suggest using pcpartpicker.com to find something compatible.